# Failed to archive Cocoa application with command-line tool inside Executables

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I stuck with this problem in my project, so, I tried it with an empty test project. Here is what I do.

1. Create a new Cocoa application project in Xcode.
2. Add a new command-line tool target to it.
3. Add this target to the dependencies of the cocoa app.
4. In cocoa app target build phases add Copy files build phase, Destination = Executables, add executable product to the list.

Now *Run* cocoa application. No problem, application launched. Navigate app bundle in Finder, Show package contents, executable here in Contents/MacOS. This is what I expect to be.

The problem occurs when I *archive* cocoa application, it fails with the following error:

```
(null): error: /Users/prudnikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestAppWithExecutable-hiysgipuqcktgoayxrgjfrtcxubl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/TestAppWithExecutable/BuildProductsPath/Release/TestAppExecutable: No such file or directory
```

Here is a screenshot

[image: xcode project build error]

Here is content of this directory

```
prudnikov@Vladimirs-iMac ~ $ ls -al /Users/prudnikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestAppWithExecutable-hiysgipuqcktgoayxrgjfrtcxubl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/TestAppWithExecutable/BuildProductsPath/Release/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  5 prudnikov  staff   170B Apr 26 21:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 prudnikov  staff   102B Apr 26 21:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 prudnikov  staff   102B Apr 26 21:59 TestAppExecutable.dSYM/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 prudnikov  staff   239B Apr 26 21:59 TestAppWithExecutable.app@ -> /Users/prudnikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestAppWithExecutable-hiysgipuqcktgoayxrgjfrtcxubl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/TestAppWithExecutable/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/TestAppWithExecutable.app
drwxr-xr-x  3 prudnikov  staff   102B Apr 26 21:59 TestAppWithExecutable.app.dSYM/
```

*Archiving* executable — no problems. All build settings are defaults.

I've also tried to change build configuration from Debug to Release for Run action of Cocoa application scheme. It runs successfully in this case as well.

This is very strange for me. Please advice how to do it?

**UPDATE:** It seems that I have problem with OS. People tried the same example and it worked. Then I trien to create a new account on my Mac and do the same there and it worked as well. What global configuration can cause this?

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: Permission of what directory or file? I removed everything from DefivedData directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an Answer but it's too long for a comment.

Check the parent directories

```
gdunham: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData$ ls -laeG /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData | grep -e " \\.$"

drwxr-xr-x  31 gdunham   staff   1054 Apr 15 14:29  /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData     
drwxr-xr-x  13 gdunham   staff    442 May  1 19:56  /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/Xcode
drwxr-xr-x   4 gdunham   staff    136 Mar  8  2012  /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/
drwx------@  66 gdunham  staff   2244 Apr  2 22:43  /Users/gdunham/Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  62 gdunham  staff   2108 Apr 30 14:33  /Users/gdunham
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   7 root      admin    238 Feb 20 14:16  /Users
drwxr-xr-x  34 root      wheel   1224 Apr 20 09:26  /
```

Also look at your group membership

```
gdunham: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData$ groups
staff com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_screensharing-disabled everyone _appstore localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
```

Comment: First command doesn't print anything, the difference in groups are 1) I don't have `com.apple.access_screensharing-disabled`, 2) I have 2 additional groups `com.apple.access_ssh` and `access_bpf`.

Comment: You need to run the command with your userid

  ls -laeG /Users/prudnikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData | grep -e " \\.$"

Comment: You can try doing a repair permissions using the Disk Utility App